# Google Gmail API - Delegation settings

Tags: google-api, gmail-api, google-api-java-client, google-admin-sdk

Apologies if this is covered elsewhere and I have missed it.

[Google's Email Settings API is deprecated and set to be turned off on July 7, 2017](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2016/07/gmail-api-new-endpoints-for-settings.html).

With this date looming, I have started investigating migrating our local delegated account management web application to the new API.  As you might expect, this applications allows users to list, add and delete delegate access to a Gmail account.

It currently uses the OAuth 2.0 scope of.

```
https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/{domain}/{username}/delegation
```

However, the [delegate section of the migration guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/migrate-from-email-settings#managing_delegation_settings), written in July 2016, says:

> Delegation settings are not yet available via the API.

The most recent version of the Gmail API I can find is **Gmail API v1 (Rev. 62) 1.22.0** which has no obvious support for Delegated accounts.

Ideally I want the application to keep working beyond 7th July. How should I proceed?

Comment: Delegation settings are not yet available via the API.   <-- I would remove that from your application as it is no longer supported.

Comment: @DalmTo.  Oh dear.  That is the main purpose of the application.  It fudges shared mailboxes using delegated accounts :(

Comment: I sent in some feedback on the migration page requesting they add some info on how best to proceed.    If this is a google domains account you may be able to do something with a service account.    https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation

Comment: @DalmTo Indeed, it is a working system using a service account that I am hoping to migrate to the new API before it stops working.

Comment: upper right hand corner https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/migrate-from-email-settings#managing_delegation_settings send feed back request that they tell you how to migrate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Joel Solomons of Google replied to my query on Google Cloud Connect (maybe sometimes it pays to cross post?).   He said the Gmail API will support delegation in the future. However, this has been pushed out until the end of Q2 2017.

So Google have postponed the [deprecation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/) of the Email settings API until November 15th 2017 to compensate.

**UPDATE**

This has been further delayed until sometime around September 2018

Comment: Hi Mark, could you share a code snippet where you call URL feed to add delegation? I want to call URL feed from App Scripts and not exactly sure how to do it.

Comment: Hi @s2000coder, is it an Enterprise/Education Google domain you are working with? (I think the delegation API only works with enterprise/education domains).  The functionality was part of the deprecated (but not as yet completely replaced)  Email settings API https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/

Comment: Hi Mark, I am on G Suit Basic. Is it available for this edition? If it is and the feature is not yet available in the new Gmail API, we plan to use the deprecated Gmail Setting API for now. I assume you have to use OAuth2 for Apps Script, service account, domain-wide delegation of authority for that service account as well.

Comment: I don't know for definite but I believe delegate account access is available in G Suite Basic.  Yes, you would need to use OAuth2.  I have only used the Java API, I cannot speak for the Apps Script approach.  It does seem a shame to be working on a solution that you know will be imminently replaced and is already deprecated. :(

Answer (score 3):

Google has updated the Gmail API to support delegation now.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/delegates