# Managing delegation settings

Tags: gmail-api

Customers want that they may manage Delegation via API. I found that Delegation settings are not yet available via the API.

So I need to own full information when this feature will be provided, cause I need to answer for my customers.

Can somebody provide to me this information?

Thanks a lot!

Regards,

Alex.

Comment: Check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42623328/google-gmail-api-delegation-settings) for the discussion about what workaround you can do for now. It was discussed that you may use [this approach](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) if this is a google domain account. But the rest, there is no response about the date of the release. I hope this gave you an idea.

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: I work on Gmail and the Gmail API platform.*

### Managing Delegation Settings

**We're happy to announce that we have now released the new [Gmail API delegate settings methods](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/delegate_settings), effectively replacing the long since [deprecated Email Settings API delegation settings methods](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#manage_delegation_settings).**

You can now use the standard libraries and tools found at https://developers.google.com/gmail/api to interact with the new Gmail delegate settings endpoints.

We will be publishing a blog post at https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com raising the visibility of the new delegate settings methods in the coming weeks, but I wanted to personally give you a courtesy heads-up.

#### Documentation

- Overview/introduction guide:
  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/delegate_settings
- Reference documentation: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/delegates
- Migration guide (from the deprecated [Email Settings API delegation
  settings methods](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#manage_delegation_settings)):
  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/migrate-from-email-settings#managing_delegation_settings